# How can I shorten the lines in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've got the google analytics javascript and I want to make it smaller.
But I thought that you couldn't just put an enter somewhere...
So where CAN I start a new line in this code?

```
var _gaq = _gaq || []; _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'secret']); _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

**EDIT:** Why? Because my screen is to small. It's for readability.

**EDIT2:** What about this approach? (The use of a '\')

```
 ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : '\
 http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
```

Comment: Why do you feel you need to modify the GA snippet?

Comment: If you put new lines you will not make it shorter. Did you mean make it more readable?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yes, more readable. (I guess it's my lack in English skills that I couldn't come up with a good word.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not sure why you want to do this, nor would I recommend it, but here you go.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'secret']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script');
  ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  var start;
  if ('https:' == document.location.protocol) {
    start = 'https://ssl';
  } else {
    start = 'http://www';
  }
  ga.src = start + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Comment: "var start = 'htt..." And can I 'split' that line somehow?

Comment: If improving readability is your goal then I wouldn't recommend it.  Using a backslash escapes the new line character, but that may not be obvious to another user.

Comment: But it will not disturb the code? It is a WAY of splitting this line?

Answer (score 2):

try [online YUI compressor](http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/) it works for javascript and css.

Comment: Very useful site, thanks. Though my question is about readability. It is my fault that this wasn't clear from the start.

Comment: however i have used this site a lot and it has helped me a lot. surely if you want easier readability you must write a program that replaces semicolon (**;**) with (**;\n**). just create a textarea and paste the code there and use a replace code. by the way it might change some semicolons in **for** loops if there are any, then you should correct them manually

Answer (score 2):

You can start a new line **after each semi-colon.**

Before:

```
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
```

After:

```
var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
ga.async = true;
```

To my eye, this makes it much easier to read. I wouldn't necessarily keep it this way when I deploy it, but you could.

In addition to being easier to read, this makes it easier to step through line by line if you are debugging.

Answer (score 1):

after any ';'

```
var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'secret']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
    ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

But why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually after every semicolon, but you can also do it automatically. Try entering "javascript formatter" into Google and you get [Online JavaScript Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) for example.

This is the code after "beautification":

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'secret']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function () {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```